# How to convert Angular project to angular Cil to project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular project made from Angular 2 seed project

I want to convert it to angular cli project ,So I can use the production and build tool from angular cli to speed up the project
How I can do that?

Comment: Read this: [RTFM](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-into-the-cli)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is listed in the documentation of the angular CLI at the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-into-the-cli).

but here is a very short overview:

1-install the angular CLI `npm install -g @angular/cli`

2-create a new project `ng new myNewProject`

3-move your src files to the new project except the `main.ts`

4-use relative paths for templates styles or lazy loaded NgModules

5-Remove any module.id in your component metadata

6-get rid of SystemJS (in the index.html) as CLI uses Webpack

this should get you started if you have a simple app but again check the docs for more details